# java: Why does my app crashed when i try to restart a thread?

Tags: java, android, multithreading

So i'm writing an app where i can remote control the light of another device. Now i want to have a timer that runs as long as the light is turned on and stops running when i turn them off again.

Now that works perfectly fine for the first time: Meaning when i turn the light on for the first time, the timer stars running, when i turn it off, it stops. But when i try to do that again, the app crashes. Anyone have any idea where the problem might be?

Here is my code:

```
 //thread for the timer it's in the onCreate method
        t = new Thread()
        {
            @Override
            public void run(){

                while(!(t.isInterrupted())){

                    try {
                        Thread.sleep(1000);  //1000ms = 1 sec

                        runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {

                            @Override
                            public void run() {
                                runningtime++;
                                runningTime.setText("Running since: " + String.valueOf(runningtime) + "seconds" );
                            }
                        });

                    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                        t.interrupt();
                    }

                }
            }
        };
    }
```

```
//the buttons and the button listeners 

    final Button buttonOn = findViewById(R.id.lightOn);
        buttonOn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // Code here executes on main thread after user presses button
                turnLightOn();
                //timer-thread gets started
                t.start();
                test.setText("Status: ON");
            }
        });


        final Button buttonOff = findViewById(R.id.lightOff);
        buttonOff.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // Code here executes on main thread after user presses button
                turnLightOff();
                //timer thread gets interrupted
                t.interrupt();
                test.setText("Status: OFF");
            }
        });
```

Comment: Because you can't restart a thread. See the Javadoc.

Comment: you have to create a new thread every time as you can't restart a thread.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You simply can not restart a Thread in Java

From the java API docs at https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Thread.html

> It is never legal to start a thread more than once. In particular, a
>   thread may not be restarted once it has completed execution.

Basically, you will want to recreate this thread using the same logic that you showed above. It likely makes sense to put that in a new method that returns a Thread, and then call that new method from your onClick to populate t.
Watch out for someone hammering the click button though, it could cause weird behavior.

```
 //thread for the timer it's in the onCreate method
public Thread makeNewThread() {
        return new Thread()
        {
            @Override
            public void run(){

                while(!(t.isInterrupted())){

                    try {
                        Thread.sleep(1000);  //1000ms = 1 sec

                        runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {

                            @Override
                            public void run() {
                                runningtime++;
                                runningTime.setText("Running since: " + String.valueOf(runningtime) + "seconds" );
                            }
                        });

                    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                        t.interrupt();
                    }

                }
            }
        };
    }

}
```

Comment: ok thank you very much! So would it maybe be better to not do this at all with a thread but instead with a normal timer?

Comment: @Kimo As you can't do this there's no maybe about it.

Comment: @user207421 what do you mean? Do you mean there is no other way of doing this without a thread?